# How to use Drupal's htaccess to redirect from https to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

I have this Drupal project which inherited several domains, so I have:

1. `www.domain1.com`
2. `www.domain1.co.uk`
3. `www.domain2.com`
4. `www.domain3.com`

and I want to redirect all these domain to `www.newdomain.com` and also want to redirect all requests to https to http as well as redirect all the domains above without `www` to `www.newdomain.com` and have tried a few things but it didn't work.

Here's what I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

But with the above, all old domains (`domain1.com`, `domain2.com`, etc) gets redirected to `www.newdomain.com`, however when I hit `https://domain1.com` for example (it happens with all domains above using http), it shows a blank page. When I hit `https://www.domain1.com` it shows a warning from using a self signed certificate - meaning it doesn't redirect to `http`.

I've read on a page somewhere that I should delete these lines from htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

But when I did, even the basic redirect that happens now (for instance, from `www.domain1.com` to `www.newdomain.com` stops working.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If https protocol always shows blank page, maybe there is distinct folder for it on your FTP ("httpsdocs" or something like that).

Also you should check your hosting provider's help page for more information about the https protocol and SSL certificate configurations.